# Удаление по мультииндексам

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter, анализ-данных, multi-index

Есть DataFrame:

[image]

Выбираю подмножество индексов, соответствующих `HEATID_id = 1079571`:
`data.loc[1079571]`, получаю список индексов этого DataFrame:

```
ind = data.loc[1079571].index
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу удалить элемент с индексом `'2020-03-20 12:57:00'`, соответствующий `ind[0]` из исходного DataFrame, делаю это так: `data.loc[1079571].drop(ind[0], inplace=True)`, но элемент в исходной `data` остается на месте.

Я знаю, что, если напишу `data.drop((1079571, '2020-03-20 12:57:00'), inplace=True)` -- элемент удалится,
но я прохожу циклом по DataFrame и по некоторому условию должна удалять подындексы с датой, принадлежащие некоторым ID.

Как правильно это сделать?

Пример данных:

```
ind = [np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]),
             np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), index=ind, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе пример данных в виде Python кода, текста или CSV?

Comment: да, добавила к вопросу
`

Comment: Для этих данных попробовала сделать так: `df.drop(df.loc[1].index[0])`, но это не работает

Comment: Все, я поняла: `df.drop((df.index[1][0], df.loc[1].index[0]))`, так работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сначала, для удобства, я дам имена столбцам мультииндекса:

```
In [6]: df = df.rename_axis(("HEATID_id", "DATETIME"))

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
                        col1      col2      col3
HEATID_id DATETIME
1         one      -0.273237  0.238934  0.170942
          two      -1.014915 -1.861040  1.438298
2         one       1.768788 -1.867217  2.228290
          two      -0.223731  0.510522 -0.339987
3         one      -0.692861  0.058985 -1.029659
          two      -0.914700 -2.383052 -0.423476
4         one      -0.983865  1.493552  0.261097
          two      -1.380589 -0.192062 -0.220487
```

**решение:**

переменные задающие значения индекса, по которым будем удалять данные:

```
In [8]: idx1, idx2 = 1, "two"
```

получаем значения мультииндекса, соответствующие строкам, которые мы хотим удалить:

```
In [9]: idx2drop = df.query('HEATID_id == @idx1 and DATETIME == @idx2').index
```

удаляем строки:

```
In [10]: res = df.drop(idx2drop)
```

результат:

```
In [11]: res
Out[11]:
                        col1      col2      col3
HEATID_id DATETIME
1         one      -0.273237  0.238934  0.170942
2         one       1.768788 -1.867217  2.228290
          two      -0.223731  0.510522 -0.339987
3         one      -0.692861  0.058985 -1.029659
          two      -0.914700 -2.383052 -0.423476
4         one      -0.983865  1.493552  0.261097
          two      -1.380589 -0.192062 -0.220487
```

PS данный метод также позволяет работать со списками:

```
idx1 = [1,4]
idx2 = "two"

idx2drop = df.query('HEATID_id in @idx1 and DATETIME == @idx2').index
res = df.drop(idx2drop)
```

---

```
In [18]: res
Out[18]:
                        col1      col2      col3
HEATID_id DATETIME
1         one      -0.392229  0.150130 -0.870317
2         one      -1.383410  0.038539 -1.505904
          two       0.783348  0.456165 -2.698035
3         one       2.290064  1.275575  0.055193
          two      -0.138148  0.730962 -1.987691
4         one      -2.215016  0.763966 -1.618045
```

Comment: большое спасибо!! Это отлично, то, что нужно!
Только в моем случае, получается, будет `idx2drop = df.query('HEATID_id == @idx1 and DATATIME in @idx2').index`, так как множество индексов.

Comment: А, вы об этом уже дописали)

Comment: @onetwoonexu, всегда рад помочь)